Need help to create animation to randomly change text characters in JS
I need to make animation like on this website in menu:
https://displaay.net/typefaces/retail/
Is there an existing solutions? I've tried to make it with copilot, but didn't succeed.
<script>
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    var titles = [
        'Text1',
        'Text12',
        'Text3'
    ];
    var currentIndex = 0;

    function changeTitle() {
        // Select the _H1 element
        var element = document.querySelector('._H1');
        if (element) {
            // Split the current title into characters and wrap each character in a span
            var chars = element.textContent.split('');
            element.innerHTML = chars.map(char => `<span>${char}</span>`).join('');

            // Function to change a character to a random one
            function changeChar(index) {
                if (index < chars.length) {
                    var randomChar = String.fromCharCode(Math.floor(Math.random() * (126 - 33 + 1)) + 33);
                    chars[index] = `<span class="animate">${randomChar}</span>`;
                    element.innerHTML = chars.join('');
                    setTimeout(() => changeChar(index + 1), 20); // Adjust the delay as needed
                } else {
                    // After all characters have changed, change the text to the next title
                    setTimeout(() => {
                        element.innerHTML = titles[currentIndex];
                        currentIndex = (currentIndex + 1) % titles.length; // Loop through the titles
                    }, 2000); // Wait for 2 seconds before changing the text
                }
            }

            // Start changing the characters
            changeChar(0);
        }
    }

    // Change the title immediately and then every 5 seconds
    changeTitle();
    setInterval(changeTitle, 5000); // 5000 milliseconds = 5 seconds
});


This isn't precise, but it's a start. Let me know what can be improved.
Improvement: Randomizing all the letters that aren't the same as the equivalent position letter in the target word. Pretty much like the other answer.


function randomChar() {
  return String.fromCharCode(Math.floor(Math.random() * (126 - 33 + 1)) + 33)
}

function randomWord(length) {
  var arr = []
  for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    arr.push(randomChar())
  }
  return arr.join('')
}

function wordToTarget(word, target) {
  var arr = word.split('')
  var brr = target.split('')
  var crr = []
  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (arr[i] === brr[i]) {
      crr.push(arr[i])
    } else {
      crr.push(randomChar())
    }
  }
  return crr.join('')
}

function setTitle(element, title, index, iterations, delay) {
  if (index === iterations) {
    element.innerText = title
    return
  }

  if (index <= title.length) {
    var word = randomWord(index)
  } else {
    word = wordToTarget(element.innerText, title)
  }
  element.innerText = word

  setTimeout(function() {
    setTitle(element, title, index + 1, iterations, delay)
  }, delay)
}

var titles = [
  'Display',
  'TypeFace',
  'Custom'
];
var elems = document.querySelectorAll(".word")
elems.forEach(function(elem, index) {

  setTimeout(function() {
    setTitle(elem, titles[index], 0, 100, 25)
  }, index * 300)

})
h1 {
  display: inline;
  margin-right: 30px;
}
<h1 class="word"></h1>
<h1 class="word"></h1>
<h1 class="word"></h1>




Thanks for the help, I think we can add a condition that if the character is not found randomly, then after 5-10 attempts (also random value for each character), the necessary symbol is set by itself. Because it can search for right character for too long.Also changing speed is to fast. And also, I don’t know is it searches characters from left to right or all at once(need this)?

you can fiddle with the parameters for setTitle(element, title, index, iterations, delay) - specifically iterations is maximum iterations, delay is delay between each letter change. it changes all letters at once, except those that are in place

Or add a time interval during which all characters will be set, then also add a condition that they will not be set at the exact same time, to keep the effect as on the website example.

Inspired by you initial code I did the following. It creates a randon string, and as long as that character is not the right one it will continue with another random character. Until it gets the entire string correct or 100 "rounds" has passed.


const max_count = 100;
const interval_ms = 30;

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', e => {
  document.querySelectorAll('.animated').forEach(elm => animateText(elm));
});

function animateText(element, interval) {
  if (element.initialtext) {
    element.count++;
    let randomStr = Object.keys(element.initialtext)
      .map(i => String.fromCharCode(Math.floor(Math.random() * (126 - 33 + 1)) + 33)).join('');
    element.animatedStr = Object.keys(element.initialtext)
      .map(i => (element.animatedStr[i] == element.initialtext[i]) ? element.animatedStr[i] : randomStr[i]).join('');
    element.textContent = (element.count < max_count) ? element.animatedStr : element.initialtext;
    if (element.textContent != element.initialtext) {
      setTimeout(() => {animateText(element)}, interval_ms);
    } else {
      delete element.count;
      delete element.initialtext;
      delete element.animatedStr;
    }
  } else {
    element.count = 0;
    element.initialtext = element.textContent;
    element.animatedStr = Object.keys(element.initialtext).map(i => ' ').join('');
    element.innerHTML = '';
    animateText(element);
  }
}
<h1 class="animated">Some title</h1>
<h1><span class="animated">Some</span> <span class="animated">title</span></h1>




Thanks, just added clarification comments in previous replies. I'll try to play with it when I get home.

Eventually ended up with this, would appreciate it if someone had ideas to slow down an animation at the beginning and the end (sort of easy in-out effect), because I tried several approaches and it didn't work correctly.
<script>
function randomChar() {
 return String.fromCharCode(Math.floor(Math.random() * (126 - 33 + 1)) + 33);
}

function setTitle(element, title, index, iterations, delay) {
 if (index === iterations) {
    element.innerHTML = title; // Use innerHTML to handle <br /> tags
    return;
 }
 var word = index <= title.length ? randomWord(index) : wordToTarget(element.innerHTML, title);
 element.innerHTML = word; // Use innerHTML to handle <br /> tags
 // Calculate the delay for the next character change
 var nextDelay = delay - (delay * (index / iterations) * 2); // Gradually decrease the delay more slowly
 if (index > iterations * 0.75) { // If we're in the last 25% of the iterations
    nextDelay = delay - (delay * (index / iterations) * 4); // Decrease the delay even more rapidly
 }
 setTimeout(() => setTitle(element, title, index + 1, iterations, nextDelay), nextDelay);
}

function randomWord(length) {
 return Array.from({length}, () => randomChar()).join('');
}

function wordToTarget(word, target) {
 return word.split('').map((char, i) => target[i] === char ? char : randomChar()).join('');
}

// Array of titles with variations
var titles = [
 'Text1...<br />Text1',
 'Text2...<br />Text2'
];

// Function to get a title that is not the last one displayed
function getNextTitle() {
 var lastTitle = localStorage.getItem('lastTitle');
 var nextTitle = titles[Math.floor(Math.random() * titles.length)];
 while (nextTitle === lastTitle) {
    nextTitle = titles[Math.floor(Math.random() * titles.length)];
 }
 localStorage.setItem('lastTitle', nextTitle);
 return nextTitle;
}

var elems = document.querySelectorAll("._H1");
elems.forEach((elem, index) => {
 var title = getNextTitle(); // Get a title that is not the last one displayed
 // Set a minimum height to reserve space for two lines
 elem.style.minHeight = '3em'; // Adjust '3em' based on your font size and line height
 setTimeout(() => setTitle(elem, title, 0, 22, 300), index * 50); // Initial delay set to 50ms
});
</script>


As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
